# $\mathbb{E}[\min (X_{1:n}) + \max(X_{1:n})]/2 = \mathbb{E}[\text{median}(X_{1:n})]$?

Tags: probability, median, moments, extreme-value

Say $X$ is continuous random variable, and we have $n$ iid samples, denoted as $X_{1:n}$. Then can we say the following

$$\mathbb{E}[\min (X_{1:n}) + \max(X_{1:n})]/2 = \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{median}(X_{1:n})]$$

I try with the convolution of two and start to take the expectation of it, but this seems exhausting.

Comment: I corrected the equation but because $X$ is used both as a random variable and as an $n$ sample of iid random variables, I am unsure what you mean by $\text{median}(X)$, as it can be (i) the median of the sample, in which case an expectation is required, (ii) the median of the distribution.

Comment: If this is true of all continuous random variables, it must remain true of discrete variables.  What does the equation state for samples of a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution with $p\ne 1/2$?  Is it true?  (If that still looks like too much work, you could calculate the expectations in a simple case by tabulating all $2^3=8$ possible samples when $n=3.$)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to disprove this equality is to consider the Cauchy distribution, since $\mathbb{E}[\min (X_{1:n})]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\max (X_{1:n})]$ are not defined for this distribution, while $\mathbb{E}[\text{median}(X_{1:n})]$ [is defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#cite_note-rothenberg-16) for $n\ge 3$.

However, the equality holds when the distribution of $X$ is symmetric around a value $\mu$. i.e., when $X-\mu$ and $\mu-X$ have the same distribution, since
$$\mathbb{E}[\min (X_{1:n})]-\mu=\mathbb{E}[\min (X_{1:n}-\mu)]=\mathbb{E}[-\max (X_{1:n}-\mu)]=-\mathbb{E}[-\max (X_{1:n})]+\mu$$
Therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[\min (X_{1:n}) + \max(X_{1:n})]/2 = \mu = \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{median}(X_{1:n})]$$

Answer (score 2):

No. Rather than prove otherwise, I wrote some quick code in R to demonstrate this is false.

I generate samples from $X \sim exp(1)$ which has median $\log(2)$. Observe

```
minX <- rep(NA,5000)
maxX <- rep(NA,5000)
medX <- rep(NA,5000)

for(i in 1:5000){
  X <- rexp(10000,1)
  minX[i] <- min(X)
  maxX[i] <- max(X)
  medX[i] <- median(X)
}

mean(maxX)+mean(minX);
mean(maxX)-mean(minX);
mean(medX); log(2)

> mean(maxX)+mean(minX);
[1] 9.792494
> mean(maxX)-mean(minX);
[1] 9.792292
> mean(medX); log(2)
[1] 0.6931122
[1] 0.6931472
```

As you can see, the two are clearly not equal. If they were, the WLLN would have ensured that this simulation would reflect this.

Sometimes it's best to just simulate before getting bogged down into deriving something that might be false.